# Background grid or guidelines in draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I am sketching house floor plans. In the Diagram Format Panel there is a point size adjustment next to the **grid** setting, but it does not seem to do anything. Any tips?

Comment: It should be one question per question. Please split into multiple questions if you have more than one.

Answer (score 3):

In the options panel on the right side un-check the guide box. Then set your grid settings to your required size.

Any shape you add will start of as its normal size. When you re-size it it will conform to the grid settings. Also, moving a shape will conform to grid settings.

Comment: OK, I now understand grid, and its point size setting. Thank you. Then what are Guides?